# WCF Service Reference as array vs. List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

We have an asp website with service references to a WCF project. We have set the configuration of the service collection type to System.Collection.Generic.List, yet the reference.cs is showing arrays. We can see

```
<CollectionMappings>
      <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.List`1" Category="List" />
</CollectionMappings>
```

in the reference.svcmap.

We would prefer to work with List if possible. What are we missing? Why is it insisting to build a reference full of arrays when it has been told to convert them to Lists?

Visual Studio 2019, asp.net 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that run across this: It’s actually an “undocumented feature” of visual studio... thank you Microsoft. When using the XML Serializer instead of the DataContract serializer, the service connection tool in visual studio doesn’t create the classes as requested. You can manually alter the reference.cs, or move to webAPI using .net core.

Answer (score 0):

Set in the Add Service Reference tool:

[image]

[image]

Finally, apply this setting to generate a proxy class.

Comment: As I said in the question, we did that. It doesn’t work.

Comment: It works fine on my computer. You can try to re-use "Add Service Reference" to generate the proxy class, and then follow my steps above to set.

Comment: We did that. That's exactly what we did was add a service reference and set the collection to Generic.List. We've done this both in asp and in wpf to same WCF. It is only generating arrays.

Comment: Could this be caused by the project? You can try to create a new project to add a service reference to see if this problem occurs.

Comment: It’s actually an “undocumented feature” of visual studio... thank you Microsoft. When using the XML Serializer instead of the DataContract serializer, the service connection tool in visual studio doesn’t create the classes as requested.